# How to make inline function only take up one copy's worth of memory space in executable file

Tags: android, c, linux, windows

Is there a way to make an inline function (which has certainly been inlined by the compiler), which is present in multiple locations in the program, only take up as much memory in the executable file as if it were not inline and/or only had one inlined instance? Theoretically, this should be possible, since the function would just have to be loaded from memory once, and its loaded contents (in RAM and/or cache) would be copied to the other necessary locations in RAM in order to both increase performance and reduce space taken in the hard drive. Android is what I am mainly concerned about, but I would be grateful to hear answers about other operating systems other than android as well.

Comment: Inlining functions doesn't mean *at all* that the compiler would copy the contents verbatim into each invocation instance. Also, the operating system tags are highly irrelevant. I suggest that instead of asking questions you would research first.

Comment: If you don’t want the code inlined, don’t mark it for inlining. Then you’ll have one copy of the code in the executable.  If you want the benefits of inlining, accept that there’ll be multiple copies of the code around, though those copies may in fact be different from each other because of optimization to the context where it is called. Choose one; you can’t have both, regardless of how much you’d like to.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala The code can be inline, but only have one copy in the HARD DRIVE, but multiple inlined copies in the RAM where it resides. And how is a funtion actually inlined (not the keyword) if it doesn't reside in multiple locations in memory? I suggest that you learn how executables work amd read the question thoroughly before answering questions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I was saying that there would only be one copy in the hard drive, and multiple inlined copies in the code section if the RAM.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you want to have a cake and eat it too. The whole point of inlining is in putting duplicate of the function at the place of its call.

But this shouldn't worry you too much as in many cases inlined code is much smaller than the original function due to the fact that it misses register saving/restoring, has some parts of it removed due to them being evaluated at compile time etc. If your function is relatively small, inlining it might actually generate smaller code than the code required to actually call existing copy of a function.

If you think you might have issues with code size, you should really post some examples and explain why do you think this is an issue.

Currently the closest thing to what you describe is JIT (Just-In-Time) compilation which allows you to have a single copy of a function written in a high level (and thus vpossibly very compact) represenation that can later be translated to machine code on the fly. This is what Android's VM does btw.

---

If you are worried about program loading times, you probably shouldn't worry about few functions. First, code will be loaded from device in (most likely) 4 KiB pages. To reduce load time you need to reduce your code size by at least 1 page to have some improvement, otherwise you don't really win anything.

Keep in mind that data is usually loaded from non-volatile storage once and kept in OS cache e.g. in most cases code is already in RAM.

Even if you are able to achieve what you want (using some sort of JIT translation), you should remember that doing translation on the fly also costs time and requires more RAM as you will keep both original high level code and resulted machine code, thus pushing data out of cache, potentially slowing loading speed of other programs.

Comment: What I tried to explain is that I'm trying to make the executable only have one copy of the function, but load that single copy into memory, and make the other copies from that one from RAM.

Comment: Lets assume you can have a single copy of a function in an executable that should be used in multiple places. How do you transfer control to it? The answer it - you have to do a function call. Which means that function was not inlined. Or you can use JIT compilation and this will allow you to inline in on the fly. For small functions you really shouldn't worry about this since calling that function can take more code than executing it directly. Inlining in those cases can reduce code size.

Comment: But before the program's instructions must be loaded into RAM before it is run. Based on this fact, I wondered if it would be possible to store only one copy of the function's instructions in the hard drive, and load it multiple times into RAM.

Comment: @cppplus1: No, and what you're asking for does not make any sense. Even if it were something you could do, it wouldn't make sense, because storage space is dirt cheap and present in abundance, and RAM is a relatively expensive, limited resource.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of inlining is that it allows the compiler to change, specialize, and optimize the function based on the other code around it. This means each inlined "copy" ends up different, operating on different registers and memory offsets and with different conditional branches optimized out. Trying to use the different versions of the function as if they were interchangeable would just break everything.